# ommiting articles before the expression "rock bottom"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can anyone tell me why an article is left out before the expression "rock bottom" despite the word "bottom" being a countable noun? For example:

> My sport career has fallen down to rock bottom.

Would it not be better to insert the article *a*?

Comment: I would just say it's just an idiomatic usage of the phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is just an idiomatic usage.

Also, we usually *hit* rock bottom:

> After that, my career hit **rock bottom**.

Taking a more literal approach, you could look at *bottom*, but

> I was at **the bottom** of the river of my life.

but then the article is back. So I don't believe a literal explanation will suffice.

Comment: I tried to think of another expression that behaved similarly – such as *dead center* – except articles are often used with _dead center_, more so than with _rock bottom_. This is a thorny question, no doubt!

Comment: Also idiomatic, if you're describing its current state, would be to say "My career is *at* rock bottom."